# replace text python 2 leters replace

Tags: python

I only want to change the text when there are both letters

```
def replaceonce(s, letters = '', replacewith=''):
    letters = set(letters)
    res = ''
    for l in s:
        if l in letters:
            res += replacewith
            letters.remove(l)
            replacewith = ''
        else:
            res += l
    return res

print(replaceonce('yday',letters='ya',replacewith='z'))
```

this code change to `zdy`  although there is `a` letter and is not in text

```
print(replaceonce('yday',letters='ya',replacewith='z'))

output

ydz or dyz or zyd all combinations are ok fine
```

I want the text to change as well

that it will look like this

```
azdry
output
or another order of letters
zdrz
```

if two letters will appear in the text to change only if there are both letters, so y + and in this example

Comment: The requirements are exceedingly unclear.  Please revise.

Comment: zdy although there is a letter and is not in text   they only need to change it if both letters are in the text @S3DEV

Comment: What is the expected output of your example?

Comment: “There is a letter” *Which* letter? “They only need to change”. *What* is ‘they’ and ‘change’ to what? “Both letters”. Which ‘both’ letters?  “In the text”. *What* text?  See where I’m going with this?  You need *explicit* requirements; please revise the question.

Comment: @yondaime done hopefully it will be understandable

Comment: @S3DEV letters='ya'  this 2 leters

Comment: so you are giving a 4-letters string to the function and it will produce a 3-letters string. Has the function to change the first occurrence of the given `letters`? Sorry, I still have doubts..

Comment: @yondaime the order can be arbitrary 4-letters string to the function and it will produce a 3-letters string yes

Comment: @yondaime and only one result

if there will be ayay the result will be zya or in another order of letters

Comment: Take your example: The function gets `s ='yday'`,  `letters = 'ya'`.  First of all it checks if both `y` and `a` are in the string `s`.why does the fuction substitute the first `y`, the first `a` but not the second `y`?

Comment: @yondaime if `ya ya` is in the text

so the text will change only once so there will be a result and the solution will be

`yaz`  and it must change even if these two letters are not an example

`yfaga`
so the result will be at this

`zfag` (no matter what order I will result in it is a correct replacement of letters) The letters can be resolved in any order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code returns the expected outputs for both the examples:

```py
def findIndexes(string, letters):
    indexes = []
    for c in letters:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if string[i] == c:
                indexes.append(i)
                break
    return indexes 
        

def replaceonce(s, letters = '', replacewith=''):
    allPresent = True
    toRet = ''
    # checking if all letters' chars are in s
    for c in letters:
        if c not in s:
            allPresent = False
            break
  
    if allPresent:
        # this block make the substitution

        # getting the index of first occurrence of each
        # letters' char inside the s string
        indexes = findIndexes(s, letters)
 
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if i not in indexes:
                toRet += s[i]
        toRet += replacewith

    return toRet
```

Your examples make the substitution for one occurrence of the `letters` string, even if the string is splitted somewhere inside the `s`. Then the idea is: find the index where this chars are and skip all of them when reconstruct the `s` string. At the end of code, add the `replaceWith` at the end of reconstructed string.
I hope that I understood correctly your question that, by the way, was not very clear.